# Form not posting what i need it to

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, file

I am experimenting with php,
How ever i can't find out how to post input data from one file to an other one.

This is the current code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['mysql'])) {
$my_file = 'test/core/config.php';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$data = '<?php
//connect to db
$host = "$host";  //i want the form value to be imported here
$user = "$user";
$port = "$port";
$pass = "$pass";
$db = "$db";

$sql = conn($host, $user, $port, $pass, $db);
 ?>';
fwrite($handle, $data);
}
?>
```

Here is the html form

```
<form class="form" action="testinstall.php" method="post">
<label for="host">Host</label>
<input type="text" name="host">
<label for="user">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="user">
<label for="port">Port</label>
<input type="text" name="port">
<label for="pass">Password</label>
<input type="text" name="pass">
<label for="db">Databace</label>
<input type="text" name="db">
<button type="submit" name="mysql">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: When i do that it coms out as

Comment: <?php
//connect to db

Comment: $host = "$host";

Comment: $user = "$user";

Comment: $port = "$port";

Comment: $pass = "$pass";

Comment: $db = "$db";   //Databace name

Comment: $sql = conn($host, $user, $port, $pass, $db);
 ?>

Comment: Do you need to get form data in another page and save it in db ?

Comment: I want to get it from the current file and save it in a different file but yes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try in this away:

```
$data = "<?php
//connect to db
$host = '$host';
$user = '$user';
$port = '$port';
$pass = '$pass';
$db = '$db';
   
$sql = conn($host, $user, $port, $pass, $db);
?>";
```

You should use " outer to print values of variables.

Comment: I shall try that

Comment: is this better?

Comment: $host = $_POST['host'];

Comment: See im tot all to familiar with php

Comment: It's a better way to concat pieces of information. Please, try to put all your questions in a single comment, it's better to people read and try to help you. Try my answer and if it does not fix you do new comment. Alright, tks.

Comment: Did you check my answer before vote down? Your issue is printing values in string because you used wrong " & '. My answer will change your output at least. Tks

Comment: yea i did but i dod figure something out with your print suddgestion ty